# Dependency injection pattern in NodeJS

Tags: javascript, node.js, dependency-injection

Recently, i've started dabbling into nodeJS.

Now i know that dependency injection is the go to pattern to decoupling code and keeping it all organized.

However, what do you do when you have one dependency that uses other dependencies?

For example, lets say i have a invest module which uses the database module and the user module, the user module also uses the database module.
And suppose i have an withdrawal module that uses the invest module, database module and the user module. Is it smart to define a property in the module's object and inject the other dependency into it throughout the application?

```
const dbc = require('./dbc');
const user = require('./user');
const invest = require('./invest');
const withdraw = require('./withdraw');

let user.dbc = dbc;
let invest.user = user;
let invest.dbc = dbc;
let withdraw.invest = invest;
let withdraw.user = user;
let withdraw.dbc = dbc;
```

Is this the best/smart way to go about doing this? Something feels wrong about this.
Sure, i could just inject the database module into user module and inject the user module into invest module, and the invest module into the withdrawal module. But something about this doesn't feel clean either.

If someone should show me the light, the community acccepted standard practice of going about this, that would great.

Comment: require("dbc") inside of the user, invest and withdraw module. nodejs should do the rest...

Comment: @Jonasw What about the invest module requiring the user module? and the withdrawal module requiring the invest and user module?..Well they dont "require" those modules, but they make calls to methods defined in those modules.

Comment: require them all, thats the cleanest and bulletproof way. if you edit your code in 10 years, you will have forgotten that you need to pass references from each module to another. require gives a nice crash if the module loading fails

Comment: @Jonasw Okay, that is clean, but lets take the db module for example. I would need to create a connection everytime i need to use it and then close it wouldn't I?

Comment: no, you can create it in the module, then put it into module.exports

Answer (score 0):

It is absolutely fine to require a module more than once. NodeJS executes the code in the module only once and remembers what the module exported.

When you require the module a second time, the module is not executed a second time (and doesn't create another database connection). Instead, the result of `require('./dbc')` will always by a reference to the same object that represents the database connection.

Answer (score 0):

The built-in NodeJS Dependency Injection is not enough for me. Here is the reasons:

1. It doesn't naturally have component life cycle management, i.e Singleton, Transient, and Wrapped. Say if you wanna use a module as singleton in a context but transient in another context, you will have to deal with having two different factory methods for the module creation.
2. Injecting dependencies to a module body via 'require()' is not recommended as it takes central dependency management off our hands. Besides, it makes it hard to resolve Circular Dependency although this problem seldom happens.

Those motivated me to find a better DI for NodeJS apps. There're quite a few of them out there. I also wrote a lightweight DI for myself. Give it a try here if you think it helps: https://github.com/robo-creative/nodejs-robo-container

With DI's supports, I'm able to stick to declaring every module as a type, no more factory methods for them. Module life cycle will be managed by the container. Your code will look like:

```
var $ = require('robo-container');

// dbc should only be a type, we can restrict it to have only one instance.
$.bind('dbc').to(require('./dbc')).asSingleton();

// following statements use Property Injection
// user should be a type that may have multiple instances (transient).
$.bind('user').to(require('./user')).set({ dbc: 'dbc' });

// invest and withdraw should be types.
$.bind('invest').to(require('./invest')).set({ user: 'user', dbc: 'dbc' });
$.bind('withdraw').to(require('./withdraw')).set({ user: 'user', dbc: 'dbc', invest: 'invest' });
```

The binding statements above use Property Injection. If your 'withdraw' module has a constructor that accepts user, dbc and invest, you can use Constructor Injection like this:

```
// the withdraw module.
function WithdrawModule(user, dbc, invest) {

    this.doSomething = function() {

    }
}

$.bind('withdraw').to(require('./withdraw')).use('user', 'dbc', 'invest');
```

To create withdraw instance, call $() or $.resolve():

```
var withdraw = $('withdraw'); // or $.resolve('withdraw');
withdraw.doSomething();
```

That's it. Hope you have the answer for your questions.